# exchanging initial consonants: name that spooneristic practice

Tags: slang

Recently I came across the expression "dain-bramaged".  I assume that there are other seemingly flippant instances of the exchange of initial consonants of words, but is there a general term for such a practice?

Edit:  Please note, this refers specifically to (a) initial consonants only, and not to whole syllables, and (b) intentional, not accidental or ignorant, exchange of consonants.

Second edit:  By popular (and quite reasonable) demand, I am emphasizing that, yes, these are spoonerims.  So what I'm looking for is a name for the paricular activity of deliberately creating a spoonerism by changing only initial consonants or consonant groups, and changing only that.

Comment: There is not, as far as I know, a term in English for that refers specifically to switching the initial consonant(s) in two words, and nothing else; _spoonerism_ is a broader term that encompasses this, but also covers other switchings. There is an expression for it in Danish, though: _bakke snagvendt_ (‘balking tackwards’ literally translated), which originated in a children's TV show back in the 1980s.

Answer (score 3):

It's known as a ***spoonerism***¹, and it's not solely restricted to consonants):

Per [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/spoonerism) (Oxford Dictionaries Online):

> ***spoonerism***: *a verbal error in which a speaker accidentally transposes the initial sounds or letters of two or more words, often to humorous effect, as in the sentence* "you have hissed the mystery lectures" *accidentally spoken instead of the intended sentence* "you have missed the history lectures."

Though I quibble with the characterization that the transposition must be accidental.

[Wikipedia confirms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spoonerism) it can be a deliberate play on words:

> *A **spoonerism** is an error in speech or deliberate play on words in which corresponding consonants, vowels, or morphemes are switched (see metathesis) between two words in a phrase.*

My personal favorite spoonerism is *butterflies flutter by*.

---

¹ <sub>As Wikipedia notes, the broader phenomenon is know as ***[metathesis](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metathesis_(linguistics))***, the famous example being the substitution of *[nucular](http://www.slate.com/articles/news_and_politics/explainer/2002/09/why_does_bush_go_nucular.html)* /ˈnjuːkjələr/ for *nuclear*.</sub>

Comment: The mnemonic for metathesis is, of course, _methatesis_. See also haplogy and wabiawization.

Comment: Note: that article is incorrect in calling _nucular_ a case of metathesis. It's not metathesis; _nucular_ consists of entirely different phonemes than _nuclear_. It's a case of a rebracketed word getting its not-so-common suffix swapped out for a more common one that happens to have almost—but not quite—the same phonemic structure.

Comment: Spoonerisms are usually accidental.  This switching is meant to be cute.

Comment: @Bill Read the second quote and citation in my answer, please: everything after "*I quibble with the characterization that the transposition must be accidenta*l", through "*A spoonerism is .. or **deliberate play on words***", down to "*My personal favorite spoonerism is butterflies flutter by*".

Comment: @BillEvansatMariposa: That just makes it a deliberate spoonerism.

Comment: @Ignacio: Right-o.  But I was looking for a term specific to exchanging single consonants or consonant groups (like br-).

Comment: @Bill The consonant thing is a separate concern (from accidental-vs-deliberate). As I said in the initial sentence of my answer, spoonerisms are not solely restricted to consonants. And as Janus mentioned, I [don't think there exists](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/275116/exchanging-initial-consonants-name-that-practice/275117?noredirect=1#comment607349_275116) such a term which would satisfy that constraint.

Answer (score 1):

They're called spoonerisms, after Reverend William A. Spooner.  Look here for a linguistic analysis: [The non-anomalous nature of anomalous utterances](http://129.237.66.221/P800/fromkin.pdf).

Comment: Spoonerisms are usually accidental. This switching is meant to be cute.

Comment: @BillEvansatMariposa, So?

Comment: Yes, it's a spoonerism.  See the second edit to the original question.